Entity Framework. Strange behavior when directly editing collection navigation property
I have the following EF models. Code is simplified to make it short. 2 related pairs of entities:
public class Resource
{
     public long Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
     public List<ResourceRole> ResourceRoles { get; set; } = new List<ResourceRole>();
}

public class ResourceRole
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long ResourceId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public Resource Resource { get; set; }
}

public class RequestTemplate
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public List<AccessSet> AccessSets { get; set; } = new List<AccessSet>();
}

public class AccessSet 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long? RequestTemplateId { get; set; }
    public bool IsAccess { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuperadmin { get; set; }
    public RequestTemplate RequestTemplate { get; set; }
}

The only difference is that one FK is long and another one is long?.
I have a problem, that same scenario does work for ResourceRole and doesn't work for AccessSet.
Here is the demo code:

I'm getting an exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'AccessSet' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 7}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.'

If I change
public long? RequestTemplateId { get; set; }

to
public long RequestTemplateId { get; set; }

then AccessSet can be updated smoothly.
So, I am confused why the same scenario does work for LONG and does not work for LONG?.
Thanks in advance!
(I appreciate if we skip a discussion related to a chosen approach of updating related entities in the database)

I have found a good article and fixed the problem:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/relationship-changes
Here is the fix that I inserted after loading an entity for the database:
 context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
  .Where(e =>  template.AccessSets.Contains(e.Entity))
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(e => e.State = EntityState.Deleted);

How I figured it out? First, I called DetectChanges and inspected a debug view and noticed 2 AccessSets with the same Id = 7. One of them had modified RequestTemplateId
AccessSet {Id: 7} Modified
    Id: 7 PK
    IsAccess: 'False' Modified
    IsSuperadmin: 'False' Modified
    RequestTemplateId: <null> FK Modified
  RequestTemplate: <null>

AccessSet {Id: 7} Modified
    Id: 7 PK
    IsAccess: 'False'
    IsSuperadmin: 'False'
    RequestTemplateId: <null> FK Modified Originally 1 <---- THIS ONE
  RequestTemplate: <null>

So, I wondered why it has been modified. Here I am not 100% sure but my theory is below.
In EF ChangeTracker there is a property DeleteOrphansTiming which is by default Immediate. If you read this section of the article I mentioned above, you will see that orphans with non nullable FK are marked as Deleted immidiately because it is not possible to have null as FK value.
But it looks like for long? EF think that null is okay. When it is removed from the navigation property collection then instead of marking this entity for the deletion it is updating RequestTemplateId from 1 to null and keep tracking of it. Later entity with the same Id is inserted into the navigation property collection and I got what you saw in the original post.

Make sure you aren't using a long-lived context. Your answer doesn't explain why you have this conflict in the first place, but it seems you are holding on to tracked entities for too long to have problems like this - your demo code in the question would never have this problem. See the-dbcontext-lifetime
